# How to Persist Accumulator with break page

Tags: vba, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have the following code in my Report on SSRS

```
Public  Dim GrupoActual as String = "" 
Public  Dim acumulado as Double
Public  Dim acumulado2 as Double

Public Function Acumulador(ByVal MiGrupo as String, ByVal value as Double, ByVal Campo as String) As Double

If (GrupoActual <> MiGrupo) Then
    If (Campo = "VolumenTotal")
    acumulado2=acumulado2 + value
    Return acumulado2
    End If

    If (Campo = "VolumenSeleccion")
    acumulado=acumulado + value
    Return acumulado
    End If  

    GrupoActual=MiGrupo
End If

End Function
```

The thing is, the values of each Accumulator resets on each page break, one way to solve this is have the whole report in one page and that is not possible.

Another thing I saw in another forum was to declare the variables as `Public Shared`

Te problem with this is even if it works with page breaks when I want to export to Excel all the values doubled.

Is there a way to bypass this problem with each page break and persist the values?

**EDIT:**
What I did to bypass this problem is to save my data in a hashtable:

```
Public Shared Dim gruposVolTotal As New System.Collections.HashTable()
Public Shared Dim gruposSeleccion As New System.Collections.HashTable()
Public Shared Dim GrupoActual as String = "" 
Public Shared Dim acumuladoSeleccion as Double = 0
Public Shared Dim acumuladoVolTotal as Double = 0


Public Function Acumulador(ByVal MiGrupo as String, ByVal value as Double, ByVal Campo as String) As Double

If (GrupoActual <> MiGrupo) Then

    If (Campo = "VolumenTotal") then 
        If (not gruposVolTotal.Contains(MiGrupo)) then
            acumuladoVolTotal=acumuladoVolTotal + value
            gruposVolTotal.Add(MiGrupo,acumuladoVolTotal)
            Return acumuladoVolTotal
        Else
            Return gruposVolTotal(MiGrupo)
        End If 
    End If

    If (Campo = "VolumenSeleccion")  then 

        If(not gruposSeleccion.Contains(MiGrupo)) then
            acumuladoSeleccion=acumuladoSeleccion + value
            gruposSeleccion.Add(MiGrupo, acumuladoSeleccion)
            Return acumuladoSeleccion
        Else
            return gruposSeleccion(MiGrupo) 
        End If 

    End If  

    GrupoActual=MiGrupo

End If

End Function
```

So Everytime I change pages thanks to the page break my data dont change as now they have their value stored in the hashtable with its proper Key.

Comment: I've never had my variables reset before. I usually use **PRIVATE** instead of **PUBLIC** for my **DIM** statements - maybe that's the issue?

Comment: I tried that and everytime I change the page the value is lost.

Answer (score 0):

I would be willing to guess that since you're using global variables they are accidentally being referenced and consequently changed elsewhere, that's the problem with globals. More than likely you're going to have to [step](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172744.aspx) through your code to determine exactly when the variables are changing and what is happening in the broader environment that could cause this.

It may also help to use `Option Explicit` at the beginning of your module, this helps you to suss out a lot of common bugs involving variable identifiers.

Usually a reliance on global variables is symptomatic of a rushed design. Think through the flow of your program to see if there might be a way to get the results you want and *eliminate* those globals, that way you can prevent that whole family of problems from being possible.

Comment: Thanks drog, check the edit I did. Sadly there are no modules in SSRS that I know of, it is a custome code in case the expressions already built in in SSRS are not enough for you.